# Render a choice widget row without enclosing <li> tags

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

Using symfony 1.4. I have the following widget declaration in my form:

```
'region' => new sfWidgetFormChoice(array('expanded' => true,'choices' => $region)),
```

In my template I render the region wiget as follows:

```
echo $form['region']->render();
```

The resulting HTML code looks like this:

```
<li><input name="recipecreate[region]" type="radio" value="2" id="recipecreate_region_2" />&nbsp;<label for="recipecreate_region_2">America</label></li>
<li><input name="recipecreate[region]" type="radio" value="3" id="recipecreate_region_3" />&nbsp;<label for="recipecreate_region_3">Asia</label></li>
```

So in my browser it looks like this:

- o America
- o Asia

I just want to have this way:

```
o America   o Asia
```

How can I get rid of `<li>` tag?

Thanks!

Gunnar

Comment: You are probably looking at this problem the wrong way. It looks like you could solve this with CSS without changing the HTML. Did you investigate that option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could accomplish the desired effect with some basic CSS, without modifying the outputted HTML. Something along these lines:

```
#recipecreate_region {
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
#recipecreate_region li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Simple, but I just didn't think about it! Thanks!